# Too many arguments to '' in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save from list field that have more than one data on it, how to save all of it at once?
I've try this code

```
    Dim detail As New Detail
    Dim detailBr As New DetailBridge
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To lstProduct.Items.Count - 1
        detail = detailBr.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(ddlGroup.SelectedValue), lstProduct.Items(i).Value) 'error was here
    Next
```

but I got an error in `lstProduct.Items(i).Value` the error said

> Too many arguments to '...'

I'm not sure what the error is.

can anyone help? Thanks for advice.

UPDATE : `detailBr` is class and the code is

```
Public Function Insert(ByVal GroupID As Integer, ByVal ProductID As String) As Boolean
    Dim iResult As Integer
    Dim arrColumn() As String = {"GroupID", "ProductID"}
    Dim arrValue() As Object = {GroupID, ProductID}

    oConn.Open()
    Dim SQLString As String = GenInsert("DetailGroup", arrColumn, arrValue)

    Try
        iResult = SCommand.Execute(SQLString, oConn)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        oConn.Close()
    End Try

    If iResult > 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: whatever `detailBr` is, the insert method doesnt take 2 arguments

Comment: `detailBr` is class, already update my question.

Comment: what is lstProduct, a ListBox? is it storing a Type?

Comment: lstProduct is ListBox

Comment: What is the part of the error you have omitted?  Why not include the entire error message in your post?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the GenInsert Function. Its last two arguments are arrays.

```
Dim arrColumn() As String = {"GroupID", "ProductID"}
Dim arrValue() As Object = {GroupID, ProductID}

Dim SQLString As String = GenInsert("DetailGroup", arrColumn, arrValue)
```

> A procedure can define only one parameter array, and it must be the last parameter in the procedure definition. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/538f81ec(v=vs.100).aspx)

In simple words you can have only one parameter as array in GenInsert function either arrColumn or arrValue

However, to solve your current problem you can use two dimensional array as parameter as in [passing-two-dimensional-array-through-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501014/passing-two-dimensional-array-through-functions) and [MSDN: Arrays as Return Values and Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#Anchor_5)

Comment: `you can have only one parameter as array` this is not true.  You can only have one argument defined as `ParamArray` but you can define [more than one parameter as an array](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6OHpYD).  The wording is confusing though.  That is also not the line the OP *says* they get the error on, but they are not being very clear.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes wording is (was until now) confusing, thanks for clarifying.